# What does the notation $\big(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\big)_V$ mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, physics

In a book about thermodynamics, I came across the notation shown in the title. A more complete example would be
$$dU = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V\; dT + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T\; dV$$
But I have no idea what the subscript means in this notation, would love some help.

I ran in to trouble with an exercise that said

> Assume that gases behave according to a law given by $pV = f(T)$, where $f(T)$ is a function of temperature. Show that this implies $$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V = \frac1V\frac{df}{dT}$$

Comment: It means that the derivative is taken with volume kept constant.

Comment: I never understood, why they use this notation in thermodynamics. They actually want to emphasise that you take the partial derivative and not the total derivative.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Suddenly there problems are more exercises in dexterity than anything else :)

Comment: @MrYouMath It is because in thermodynamics you really have quantities understood as functions of different sets of variables, instead of just having functions. For example $U(S,V)$ and $U(T,V)$ are the same quantity in different variables. The corresponding $V$ partial derivatives are generally not the same.

Comment: Hear, hear! @Ian you have touched upon the exact stumbling block for people in understanding those partials. (+1 if this were an answer).  OP, when partials are taken, you have say holding *what* constant (and that matters to the value of the derivative).  Often, it's understood what is kept constant, so we omit it.  As Ian points, in thermodynamics, we do need to be explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ian's comment above is spot-on, but I think it could benefit from some elaboration, so I'll write up a more detailed explanation. We all know that a partial means treat the other variable as constant. It's all about the fact that the other variable could mean any number of things.

When a mathematician thinks of a function, it is a "map" which to each set of values of the argument variables associates a value of the function. So $U = f(T,V)$, for example, defines a value, $U$, for each ordered pair $(T,V)$ in the domain of $f$. But physicists like to write that simply as $U(T,V)$. $U$ here is not a function in the strict mathematical sense: it is a physical quantity whose value happens to depend on $T$ and $V$ (more than that: it is uniquely determined by $T$ and $V$).

In thermodynamics, the state of a system can be described by different sets of variables. In the simplest situation, some fixed amount (mass) of substance (with uniform properties) can be described by any two of temperature $T$, pressure $p$, volume $V$ and entropy $S$. For any such system, the equations of state relate these to each other and allow one to switch from one pair to another as convenient for a given purpose (just as one can change from rectangular to polar coordinates to specify a point in the plane).

Suppose, for example, that $U(p,V) = c p V$ (this is valid for ideal gas), where $c$ is some constant. What if I wanted instead to find how the same quantity, internal energy, would be expressed in terms of $T$ and $V$? It would be very wrong to simply write $U(T,V) = c T V$ by simply replacing $p$ with $T$ in the formula, as one would with any mathematical function. What is important is to preserve the meaning of $U$ - it's value for a given state of the system - so we use the equation of state to express $p$ in terms of $T$ and $V$ and then substitute. For ideal gas we would get $U = b T$, where $b$ is another constant (because the ideal gas equation of state is $p \propto T/V$). As a **function** of two variables, U is now actually different!

With the original function, we have
$$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} = cp = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_p$$
since $p$ is the second variable in that function. But with the $U$ as a function of $T$ and $V$, we'd write
$$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} = 0 = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T. $$
This is clearly different from the above.

The same also applies to $p$ itself, if it is expressed in terms of two of the other "basic" variables, as in the specific example in the question. If I have $p = f(T)/V$, then deriving the wanted result is a piece of cake. But if I had considered $p$ as a function of $T$ and $S$, I might get something very different. Suppose $pV = f(T) = KT$ with $K$ a constant (the ideal gas equation of state again). Then
$$
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V = \frac{K}{V} = \frac{p}{T} 
$$
But it can be shown that (I won't get into that here)
$$
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_S = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\frac{p}{T}, $$
where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index. You can see that the above are not equal for any value of $\gamma$.

In more complex scenarios, a thermodynamic state might not be uniquely defined in only two variables. Then any thermodynamic potential (a function of state) would be a function of maybe three, maybe more variables, and we'd have to write things like
$$  \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_{V,\; X,\; Y,\; \dots} $$

Comment: Amazingly thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Partial_derivatives):

$$\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right) _V$$

is the partial derivative of $p$ with respect to $T$ while holding $V$ constant.